# Simpe VBA sub: Error on start of function, but not after

Tags: excel, email, vba

I have a simple function to select a fixed range and prepare for email, which works... but only after running the function the second time. The issue happens right after I open the Excel spreadsheet, I would then "end" the script and run it again, then it works like a charm.

Your help is much appreciated, would very much like to understand why the error is happening.

Error: **Runtime Error 1004: Select method of Worksheet class failed.**

On debug, the line ".Parent.Select" is then highlighted from the script below.

```
Sub Select_Range_now()
   Dim Sendrng As Range
   Dim EndOfLine As Integer

   EndOfLine = Find_First() - 1
   Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Output").Range("B1:I" & EndOfLine)

   ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

   With Sendrng
       .Parent.Select
       .Select

       With .Parent.MailEnvelope
           With .Item
               .SentOnBehalfOfName = "groupemail@someemail.com"
               .To = "someothergroupemail@someemail.com"
               .CC = ""
               .Subject = "Report"
           End With
       End With
   End With
End Sub
```

### **EDIT:** New find:

When clicking on "Mail Recipient" option, I get this msgbox: [msgbox dialog](http://imagebin.org/251272)

**Email: You can send the entire workbook as an attachment to an email message or send the current sheet as the body of an email message.**

- **Send the entire workbook as an attachment**
- **Send the current sheet as the message body**

Clicking on that button again will not prompt this again and the script works right away. I'm guessing that when running the first time it seems to have trouble handling this dialog, or something!

In case anyone needs to know what the Find_First() function, it's used to find the text ENDOFLINE so I can calculate my selection range:

```
Function Find_First() As String
   Dim FindString As String
   Dim Rng As Range
   FindString = "ENDOFLINE"

   With Sheets("Output").Range("A:I")
       Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                       After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                       LookIn:=xlValues, _
                       LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                       MatchCase:=False)
       If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
           'Application.Goto Rng, True
           'MsgBox "row number: " & Rng.Row
           Find_First = Rng.Row
       Else
           'MsgBox "Nothing found"
       End If
   End With
End Function
```

Comment: I can't see why you need to Select it in the first place. You should always try to avoid Selects. If you really need to does `Activate` work instead of Select? How about `Worksheets("Output").Activate`? (You should also avoid Activates :) )

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to  `.Parent.Select` and I'm almost 100% certain that the next line, `.Select` is superfluous. What happens if you remove or comment out those 2 lines?

Comment: When using the "Mail Recipient" tool, I want to select a specific range of cells to be used for email. Would your method work better?

Comment: @XtremeHavoc not sure who you're asking, but in your example, you're including the entire worksheet in the email, not just the selected range.

Comment: @XtremeHavoc can you put your Find_First function

Comment: @DavidZemens It's actually selecting anything in this "Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Output").Range("B1:I" & EndOfLine)"

Comment: @user2063626 I have posted it above.

Comment: @DavidZemens Here's a snap shot of the selection http://imagebin.org/251270

Comment: The `Selection` you're making has nothing to do with what is being emailed. You are emailing the sheet (`With .Parent.MailEnvelope...`).  This is the `.Parent` of `sendRange`, which is the worksheet.

Comment: I think what you need to use is `PublishObjects` and then that can be attached to the body of an email. I have not really done these before but I've seen some other Q's on here about that topic.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're looking for.

Modified from an answer [I did over at SuperUser a few weeks ago](https://superuser.com/questions/552331/excel-macro-to-extract-header-and-rows-then-email/552770#552770), with add'l credit due to Ron de Bruin, some of whose code is adapted in the `RangeToHTML()` function below.

```
Sub PublishObjectFromFilteredRange()
'An example of applying autofilter to sheet
' and setting range variable = to the autofiltered cells/visible cells
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pObj As PublishObject
Dim sndRange As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim outmail As Object 'mail item

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sndRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D7:G10") '<--- Modify this line to use your sendRange

'Create & publish the PublishObject
'   Change the Filename to a location that works for you...
Set pObj = ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
    SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
    Filename:="C:\Users\david_zemens\Desktop\publish.htm", _
    Sheet:="Sheet1", _
    Source:=sndRange.Address, _
    HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)

    pObj.Publish True

'Create an instance of Outlook to send the email:
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set outmail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With outmail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "Me!"
        .To = "email@address"
        .CC = "someoneelse@address"
        .Subject = "Report"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(sndRange)
        .Send 'Or use .Display to show the message.
    End With

    OutApp.Quit


End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2010
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub Select_Range_now()

  ....

  Set Sendrng = ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets("Output").Range("B1:I" & EndOfLine)

  ....

End Sub
```

and

```
Function Find_First() As String

  ....

  With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Range("A:I")

  ....

End Sub
```

If you're running these functions from an application other than Excel, you are strongly advised to prefix `ActiveWorkbook` with the variable referencing your instance of Excel (`AppExcel.ActiveWorkbook...`) as your application can otherwise fail if a second instance of Excel is open.

Sorry, I can't address the second part of your problem at the moment.